# Can operations like convolution and pooling be discovered with a neural architecture search approach?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, neuroevolution, neural-architecture-search

From [Neural Architecture Search: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05377), first published in 2018:

> Moreover, common search spaces are also based on predefined building
>   blocks, such as different kinds of convolutions and pooling, but do
>   not allow identifying novel building blocks on this level; going
>   beyond this limitation might substantially increase the power of NAS.

Has anyone tried that? If not, do you have any thoughts about the feasibility of this idea?